# Conditionally select entire record based on a field

Tags: sql, oracle

I found two solutions to this problem.  One is hard to write and the other is slow to run.  I was wondering if there's a better way I'm missing and I'm always happy to learn new methods.

I have an address table that holds multiple records for the same customer, but different types (billing, shipping, etc.)  It might not have all types for all customers.  If they have a billing address I want to use that, if not use the shipping address.

For solution 1 I joined the table to itself and for each field had to use a case statement to pick the right address.  The when part of each case statement was the same but had to be written for every field.

```
select
case
  when billing.customer is not null
  then billing.address
  else shipping.address
end as address
from
(
select *
from personal
where type = 'billing'
) billing
full outer join
(
select *
from personal
where type = 'shipping'
) shipping
on billing.customer = shipping.customer
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c5ff/4/0

The second solution is a bit easier to write but takes longer to execute.

```
select *
from personal
where type = 'billing'
union
select * from personal
where type = 'shipping'
and customer not in (
  select customer
  from personal
  where type = 'billing'
  )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c5ff/5/0

If there's any better way that would be awesome to learn.

Comment: I'm not sure about Oracle after v8, but could you use the TOP 1 and order by address type? -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is faster:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
         row_number() over (partition by customer order by type) as rn
  from personal
  where type in ('billing', 'shipping')
) 
where rn = 1;
```

This works because `'billing'` is ordered *before* `'shipping'` and thus gets the row number 1 if both addresses are present. If you need to include other address types that do not happen to sort in the way you want them "considered", you can use a conditional sorting:

```
select *
from (
  select personal.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by customer 
                            order by 
                               case type 
                                  when 'postal' then 1 
                                  when 'shipping' then 2 
                                  else 3 
                            end) as rn
  from personal
  where type in ('billing', 'shipping', 'postal')
) 
where rn = 1;
```

This would give a postal address a higher priority than a shipping address.

Comment: This would work if the rn field you created reset to 1 on change of customer.  Since it's for a report I need it to pull a list of customers, not just one.

Comment: @Mike: I just realized that ;) You only need to include a `partition by customer` in the window definition.

Comment: I like this method a lot.  If you have more different types of addresses you could prioritize them all with just 1 more line per type.  It performs about as well as the slower version I have, but is easiest to write.

Comment: @Mike: an index on `(customer, type)` might probably speed up this query

Answer (score 4):

I would go with the second approach with two slight modifications.  First, create an index on `customer` and `type`:

```
create index idx_personal_type_customer on personal(type, customer_type)
```

And use `union all` instead of `union`:

```
select *
from personal
where type = 'billing'
union all
select * from personal
where type = 'shipping'
and customer not in (
  select customer
  from personal
  where type = 'billing'
  )
```

Comment: Exactly this, a proper index will make the inner look up lightning fast (seek).

Comment: That index becomes a permanent part of the DB right?  Or is it just created for the current session / query?  In this case it won't be run enough to warrant a permanent index, but could in heavier uses.

Comment: @Mike . . . The index is a permanent part of the database.  You might find that it is helpful in other queries as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pivot the results instead:

```
select customer,
       coalesce(max(case when type = 'billing' then address end),
                max(case when type = 'shipping' then address end)) new_address
from   personal
where  type in ('billing', 'shipping')
group by customer;
```

The index as Gordon suggested earlier wouldn't hurt, either!

Comment: I don't see how this is any easier to write, I'll have to write that whole coalesce block for each field.  Also this doesn't pick the whole record based on the field.  For example maybe the billing address doesn't have an address line 2 value but the the shipping address does.  It will mix line 1 from billing with line 2 from shipping and get bad data.

Comment: it's easier to write because it only queries the table once, rather than mulitple times like both your examples did! Your examples had no mention of address line 2, so apologies if I wasn't psychic. In other words, please make sure your test examples accurately represent the scenarios you're encountering! *{:-) In light of this new information, I'd go with the row_number() solution that @a_horse_with_no_name came up with.

Comment: I thought select ENTIRE RECORD made it clear enough.  I guess I should have built it into the example.  But listing addr1, addr2, addr3, city, state, zip, name seems overkill.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, to be fair to you, I missed that; I didn't really pay attention to the title, and it's not mentioned in the bulk of the text. Ah well, at least someone else gave you the right solution *{:-)